# Using named functions for callbacks

Tags: javascript

I have a major problem with profiling in javascript with anonymous functions, I have always many anonymous functions - most of them are callbacks - and It makes analyzing results of profiler very hard for me.

Finally I decided to use named functions for callbacks, like this:

```
var f = function(callback) {
    // Do something ...
    callback();
}

f(function named_function() {
    console.log('Sample callback function!');
});
```

I want to know that will I have any problems after making this change in my codes?
And will this type of function definition and passing reserve the name (named_function) anywhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name will only be available inside the scope of the named function expression.

But there is a problem in IE 8 and lower. It will leak out to the outer scope, and will actually create a different function object, so you should nullify it if that's a problem.

```
f(function named_function() {
    console.log('Sample callback function!');
});
var named_function = null;
```

See this article for more information: [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

Or you could create it like this to solve the IE issue.

```
f(function() {
    return function named_function() {
        console.log('Sample callback function!');
    };
}());
```

But that's a little ugly.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass anonymous functions like that, the name will exist inside the function itself.

It will not exist in any other scope.

```
var f = function(callback) {
    // Do something ...
    callback();
}

f(function named_function() {
    console.log(named_function); // Logs the function
    console.log('Sample callback function!');
});

console.log(named_function);​ // Error: named_function is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to complicate things.

Just name the function when you declare it

```
var foo = function foo(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a named callback in a scope will cause it to be visible only in that scope. I would therefore conclude that there shouldn't be any naming conflicts. For example, the following code runs as expected:

```
(function named_callback() { console.log("Callback 1"); })();
(function named_callback() { console.log("Callback 2"); })();​
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're still creating an *anonymous* function expression and assigning it to a local scoped variable `f`. Go for

```
function f( callback ) {
    callback();
}

f( named_function );

function named_function() {
    console.log('Sample callback function!');
}
```

That way, you're even avoiding the *named function expression* memory leak in <= IE8, plus since you're no longer creating a *function expression* but a *function declaration, you can even access `f` within the body.

Comment: I would not say it's an anonymous function. It does not create a symbol in the current scope, but the function has a name :)